# npm command not found even after adding its path to the $PATH variable

Tags: linux, npm, debian

I have installed Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) with Homebridge to a Raspberry Pi Zero 2W using the official installation tool.

The installation was successful and it runs smoothly.

I tried to run `npm` and I received a `command not found` error.

Using `whereis` I discovered two paths where `npm` is installed and added it to $PATH using

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebridge/bin/:/opt/homebridge/lib/node_modules/npm
```

now when I type `npm` in the terminal, it **strangely** hangs for 5 seconds and shows me this:

```
npm <command>

Usage:

npm install        install all the dependencies in your project
npm install <foo>  add the <foo> dependency to your project
npm test           run this project's tests
npm run <foo>      run the script named <foo>
npm <command> -h   quick help on <command>
npm -l             display usage info for all commands
npm help <term>    search for help on <term>
npm help npm       more involved overview

All commands:

    access, adduser, audit, bugs, cache, ci, completion,
    config, dedupe, deprecate, diff, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, exec, explain, explore, find-dupes, fund, get, help,
    help-search, hook, init, install, install-ci-test,
    install-test, link, ll, login, logout, ls, org, outdated,
    owner, pack, ping, pkg, prefix, profile, prune, publish,
    query, rebuild, repo, restart, root, run-script, sbom,
    search, set, shrinkwrap, star, stars, start, stop, team,
    test, token, uninstall, unpublish, unstar, update, version,
    view, whoami
```

So, now terminal, is at least finding where `npm` is located.

But if I try a more sophisticated command like

```
sudo npm i -g homebridge-homekit-control
```

I still see `command not found`

How do I solve this?

Comment: `sudo` uses root's `PATH`, not your own.